# Google Maps - panTo() - not working?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to allow a user to set their location and then have Google Maps pan to that location.

I can't seem to get panTo to work, instead of updating my map it just reloads the page.

Page here:
http://dub[remove]step.com/events/index.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
map.panTo(mymarker.getPoint());
```

an alternative would be

```
map.setCenter(mymarker.getPoint());
```